# How to configure Spree Address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I want to streamline Spree's checkouts for digital goods - these won't need delivering. So, in my page (see picture below) at the *Address* step, I only need the *Customer E-mail* and can remove the *Billing Address* and *Shipping address* form groups.

[image: What the page looks like now]

While I can remove some parts of the address `config/initializers/spree.rb` - `Spree::Config[:address_requires_state]` I can't find a way to completely remove the address.

Also, I found a way to change the checkout_flow, but it only removes checkout steps or reorders them. So, how could I configure Address page?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to remove or skip address during checkout then you can add a file `app/models/spree/order_decorator.rb` and add these lines

   ```
   Spree::Order.class_eval do
     remove_checkout_step :address
   end
   ```

   Here you can also provide other options like e.g delivery
2. If you want to customize address page then you simply download spree views and save that view in your APP and you can easily customize spree pages.